# Python to compute MSE for every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, mse

I am trying to compute the MSE for every row in my dataframe,

Below is my code-

```
import pandas as pd
s={'AValues':[1,1,2,2],'month':[2016,2017,2018,2019],'fvalues':[55,66,77,88],'Fruits':['Apple','Mango','Orange','Banana']}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)
mse_df=pd.pivot_table(p,index='Fruits',columns='month',values=['AValues','fvalues'])
mse_df=mse_df.fillna(0)
```

This is how the dataframe output of above code looks like-
[image]

I wanted to calculate here mse for Apples, Banana, Mango and Orange i.e row by row.
(AValues- actual values , fvalues- forecasted values)

I am trying the below code-

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mean_squared_error(mse_df['AValues'],mse_df['fvalues'])
```

But, it's giving me the total mse and not individual or row by row.

Can you please help me on how the mse can be found out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised this `mean_square_error` function you import doesn't have an axis kwarg. Instead, use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
MSE = np.mean((mse_df['AValues'] - mse_df['fvalues'])**2, axis=ax)
```

where `ax` is the axis you want the mean to be calculated over. I'm not so familiar with pandas, but if they are the same shape as numpy arrays / matrices / similar, it will probably be `axis=1`, although it could be `axis=0`

Comment: were taking in the mean to compensate for 1/n?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, sorry John. The numpy ```mean``` function sums up all the elements and divides by the number, yes. The MSE is a relatively simple computation, so we can just use numpy's ```mean```, and use that on the squared difference (hence the ```('AValues' - 'fvalues')**2``` inside it. You should also make sure you understand what the mean square error is, then hopefully my answer will make more sense. I hope that helps answer your question.

Comment: This makes sense, taking mean does the job of 1/n in the MSE, mathematically.

Comment: In MSE we have a summation in the formula, so am not sure how does it happen in the computation you mentioned, can you please elaborate here?

Comment: ```np.mean()``` takes in an array. In this instance our array is ```arr=(mse_df['AValues'] - mse_df['fvalues'])**2``` and then it performs the mean on that array. ```np.mean(arr)``` is the equivalent of ```np.sum(arr) / len(arr)```.

Comment: You should check out the documentation for the numpy ```mean``` function. This can be a bit overwhelming and complicated when you're new to programming, but the examples at the bottom of the page are usually quite helpful. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html